# Remaining AC Voltage

Tags: electrical, switch, wire, light, voltage

So I have a three switch box and one goes to a light/receptacle outlet on the wall.  The other two go to my ceiling fan.  When I read the wires out when they are switched off I get 0vac. When I turn on the switch circuit that I'm not reading with my meter, I get anywhere from 28-36vac, then I turn on the switch that I'm connected to with my meter I get 115vac.  Why am I getting the 28-36vac on my meter when I'm flipping the other switch on and off?  The wall receptacle does not have any effect on the voltage in the ceiling.

Comment: Which wires are you measuring between?

Comment: Can you plug any sort of load into the circuit?  A night-light would do (as long as it's turned on).  Then test again.  Let us know if that voltage goes away.

Comment: Phantom voltage is what you need to look up.  There are several questions about it.

Comment: Meter reading *without a load* are meaningless. You need at least a small load, e.g. 100 kilohm resistor across the meter probes, to get a useful reading.